# scikit-image feature detector, descriptor and description matching

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have a goal of comparing two images using scikit image. My plan is as follows.  Detect features on an image, get descriptors of detected features and then match descriptors between two images (compute a distance).

So far I found that scikit-learn has `CENSURE` feature detector and `Daisy` features descriptor. But it looks like `Daisy` creates description of whole image.

I wonder if there is method, which would take feature detected by `CENSURE` and create descriptors, which I can later use in `match_descriptors` method.

Comment: Do you want to compare whole images, or a "summary" of image content?  For the first, use `compare_ssim`, for the second, perhaps look at HoG (histogram of gradients).

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Thank you. I would like to compare 'summary' only. Comparing detected features of SIRF would be ideal. I will look into HoG.

Comment: If you are looking for SURF, then Censure is a good bet.  You can also extract Daisy features after detecting interest points using ORB.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt ORB is what I need. Your last comment is the perfect answer.